# Meaning of "quod si"

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation, conjunction, particle

I'm having trouble with *quod sī*. L&S offers, under the definition of *quod*,

> With other particles, as si, nisi, utinam, ubi, etc., always with reference to something which precedes (very freq.), but, though, now

and then gives a whole bunch of examples that omit whatever the "something which precedes" is, thereby removing any context.

I'm asking now because I'm trying to translate an Armenian fairy tale into Latin, and there's a noble telling a peasant girl,

> The King has sent us to ask you to become his son's wife. This ring, this necklace, these bracelets—all these are yours, if you consent!

I've translated it as follows, but I'm not sure I'm using *quod sī* correctly.

> Rēx nōs mīsit tē fīlium nūbere ōrātum, quod sī annueris, hanc ānulam, hanc armillam, hoc monīle, cūncta tibi donābit!

I'm going for something along the lines of "The king has sent us to ask you to marry his son, if you agree to  which [request], he'll give you this ring, this bracelet, [and] this necklace."

Thoughts?

Comment: To my knowledge *quod si* just means 'but if, and if', *quod nisi* 'but if not, and if not'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nubo** and **annuo** both take the dative case, giving **filio** instead of **filium**, and **cui** instead of **quod**.  **cui si** seems ok to me - '**to which if you agree.'**  But see **cnread**'s comment below regarding **quod**.

- For authentic word arrangement I would suggest **Rēx nōs tē fīlio nūbere oratum mīsit, cui sī annueris, hunc ānulum, hanc armillam, hoc monīle, cūncta tibi donābit!**  Latin usually puts verbs at the end of their clauses.  Also **Anulus** is masculine so I have put **anulum**.

Comment: Note that the dative singular of the relative pronoun is cui (or, for an archaizing effect, quoi), not quo. At any rate, when what's agreed to is a thing, an accusative object is also found, according to Oxford Latin dictionary; so Joel's quod is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thank you @cnread you are quite right.  I will amend my post accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You probably forgot to add "ask" in your translation?

Comment: Thank you Cerberus!  Well spotted you!  My attention to detail is slipping.  I will amend.

Comment: One other correction: hanc and anulum don't agree in gender.

Comment: Oh dear I am slipping.